# pytorch got None after backward()

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am learning pytorch and write a simple code as below.

```py
import torch
x = torch.randn(3,requires_grad=True).cuda()
print(x)
y = x * x
print(y)
y.backward(torch.tensor([1,1.0,1]).cuda())
print(x.grad)
```

```
tensor([ 0.5934, -1.8813, -0.7817], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
tensor([0.3521, 3.5392, 0.6111], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
None
```

if I change the code as

```py
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch
# x = torch.randn(3,requires_grad=True).cuda()
x = Variable(torch.randn(3).cuda(),requires_grad=True)
print(x)
y = x * x
print(y)
y.backward(torch.tensor([1,1.0,1]).cuda())
print(x.grad)
```

```
tensor([0.9800, 0.3597, 1.6315], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
tensor([0.9605, 0.1294, 2.6617], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
tensor([1.9601, 0.7194, 3.2630], device='cuda:0')
```

The grad is ok. But why? I hate the **Variable** class.

## env

python:3.8

pytorch:1.5

cuda :10.2

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```py
x = torch.randn(3,requires_grad=True).cuda()
```

x is create by **cuda()**. So x is not a leaf tensor.

Change the code as below will be ok.

```py
x = torch.randn(3,requires_grad=True,device=0)
```